# Java: NPE calling a method on an array element

Tags: java, arrays, class, nullpointerexception

I'm having an issue when I want to set the name of an object to another class, because I keep receiving the *NullPointerException*, and I'm not quite sure how to fix this error.

Here is an example:

**First Class:**

```
//Just excuse the Vehicle class, it's just an example
private Vehicle[] car;
private int number = 1;
private int count = 0;

public store Display()
{
    car = new Vehicle[number];
}

public void setVehicleName(String name)
{
    car[count].setName(name);
}
public String getVehicleName()
{
    return car[count].setName(name);
}
```

**Second class:**

```
//So, I have radio buttons, so I'll just skip to that code
if (addName.equals(e.getActionCommand()))
{
    name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter the vehicle name: "); //there is a private String name
    name.toLowerCase(); //automatically converted to lower case
    displayStore.setVehicleName(name); //assume an Display object called 'displayStore'
}
```

So, if anybody has an idea or know how's to fix it, I would be grateful. Thanks!

Comment: `final` is a reserved word.... what do you have in Second class named final?

Comment: Oops, that's not supposed to be `final`. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays of objects in java come default set to null so if you do

```
Vehicle [] car = new Vehicle[number];
car[1].setName("Toyota");
```

You will get a `NullPointerException` because `car[1]` is null

You need to initialize the array. So likely you will want to do this in your constructor

```
public store Display()
{
    car = new Vehicle[number];
    for(int i=0;i<number;i++) {
        car[i] = new Vehicle();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to instantiate car[count] before using it. So, replace your Display method with this:

```
public store Display()
{
    car = new Vehicle[number];
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        car[i] = new Vehicle();

    //Return some store type object here or change the type to void
    // Moreover it is better to do initialization/instantiation in the constructor, rather
    // than a separate method
}
```